# Advanced Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I'm kind of stuck on how to approach this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A dinner party host has unlimited numbers of plates in *a* different colors.
How many different arrangements of colored plates are possible at a round table which seats seven people?

If *a*=3 then the answer should be 315.

Comment: Are two "arrangement" that differ by a rotation of the table, "the same"? Do you assume that each of the $7$ places should contain a plate?

Comment: If they differ by a rotation, I'm assuming that they are they same. I guess it isn't the case that every seat has to have a plate.

Comment: It is a custom on MSE to include some context and some of your attempts; writing "if $a=3$, the answer should be 315" looks like "I don't understand it and  you should solve my homework". Then it will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will definitely put what I was thinking next time

Answer (score 2):

First, note that if an arrangement of plates uses more than one colour of plate, then there is no way to rotate it to make it the same, because 7 is prime. Thus, the number of ways to arrange plates with at least two colours is the same as arranging 7 plates of at least two different colours in a line, divided by 7. That is, it is
$$
\frac{a^7 - a}{7}.
$$
Then, there are $a$ more arrangements using only a single colour, for a total of
$$
\frac{a^7 - a}{7} + a.
$$

Comment: This is the "no-holes" variant :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think I get it now

Comment: the "yes holes" variant is the same thing except of course you have $a+1$ "colors" of plate instead of just $a$ -- one of them is Brand New InvisiPlates™!